# How to find value in DynamoDb table without partition key?

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to find values in DynamoDb table by field value, without partition key, this is how I'm trying to achieve this:

```
const tag = await database.query({
      TableName: 'blog_tags',
      KeyConditionExpression: 'tagName = :name',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':name': {S: 'test'}
   }
});
```

But I'm getting the error `ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element: tagId`

In my table, I have `tagId` as the partition key and tagName as the value field. But I want to search by `tagName` only.

How should I modify this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DynamoDB gives us two ways to fetch data: `query` and `scan`.

The `query` operation requires you to specify the primary key.  The `scan` operation lets you fetch items by specifying *any* attribute.

Therefore, if you want to fetch data form DynamoDB without using the primary key, you can use the [scan operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html).  However, be careful when using `scan`.  From the docs:

> The Scan operation returns one or more items and item attributes by accessing **every item in a table or a secondary index**.

The `scan` operation can be horribly inefficient if not used carefully.  If this access pattern is common in your application, you may want to reorganize your data such that the `tagName` is part of the primary key.  This will allow you to use the `query` operation to fetch the data you need.

Comment: technically 3 ways...don't forget `GetItem`

Comment: Right you are!  I have to find a better way to highlight what I mean.  Perhaps "DynamoDB lets you fetch data using a shovel or a bulldozer".  Hmm, maybe "scalpel or a machete".  

Comment: tweezers, shovel, or bulldozer?

Comment: Yes!  I love it!